# Alembic syntax for SQL "in" operator

Tags: python, alembic

i need the alembic syntax for an operation like

```
select id from table1 where id not in (select id from table2)
```

there doesn't seem to be any documentation anywhere on this. any pointers would be helpful

Comment: Is this in a migration? Could you not do it with straight SQL? Does this question help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11970555/modify-data-as-part-of-an-alembic-upgrade

Answer (score 1):

To execute raw SQL queries, use [`op.get_bind()`](https://alembic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ops.html#alembic.operations.Operations.get_bind) to get a [Connection](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection), then use it's [`execute`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.execute) method.

```
c = op.get_bind()
result = c.execute('select id from table1 where id not in (select id from table2)')
```

If you are only performing `update` and `delete` and don't need results, you can use [`op.execute`](https://alembic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ops.html#alembic.operations.Operations.execute) as a shortcut.

```
op.execute('delete from table2 where id in (select id from table1)')
```